# Freeing nodes in linked list causes random exits from while(1) loop

Tags: c

```
node *print_immu(node *root, unsigned char *map[HEIGHT], player *enemy){// need to check
    if(root != NULL){
       node *cur = root;
        node *tmp;  
        while(cur->next != NULL){      //if there are many > 
            if(cur->width == WIDTH - 1 || map[cur->height][cur->width + 2] == '#'){
                if(map[cur->height][cur->width + 2] == '#'){
                    enemy->lives--;
                }
                tmp = cur;
                if(tmp->prev == NULL){
                    root = cur->next;
                    tmp->next->prev = NULL;
                }else{
                    tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
                    tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
                }
                map[cur->height][cur->width] = '`';
                cur = cur->next;
                free(tmp);
                
            }else{
                map[cur->height][cur->width] = '`';
                cur->width += 2;       
                map[cur->height][cur->width] = '>';
                cur = cur->next;
            }
        }   
        tmp = cur;
        if(cur->width == WIDTH - 1 || map[cur->height][cur->width + 2] == '#'){
            if(map[cur->height][cur->width + 2] == '#'){
                enemy->lives--;
            }
            if(cur->prev == NULL){
                map[cur->height][cur->width] = '`';
                free(cur);
                root = NULL;
            }else{
                map[cur->height][cur->width] = '`';
                tmp = tmp->prev;
                free(cur);
                tmp->next = NULL;
           }
        }else{
            map[cur->height][cur->width] = '`';
            cur->width += 2;
            map[cur->height][cur->width] = '>';
        }
    }
    return
```

And here's how I create the nodes:

```
node *players_u(player *me, node *root, unsigned char *map[HEIGHT]){
    for(int i=0; i<me->size; i++){
        if(map[me->height + i][1] == '+'){
            if(me->block == '#'){
                me->lives--;
            }else{  
                if(root == NULL){
                    root = (node*)malloc (sizeof(node*));
                    root->next = NULL;
                    root->prev = NULL;
                }else{
                    node *nw = (node*)malloc (sizeof(node*));
                    nw->next = root;
                    root->prev = nw;
                    root = nw;   
                    nw->prev = NULL;
                }
                root->height = me->height + i;
                root->width = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

As I said in the title, it does its thing like 3 - 7 times correctly (it's kind of random) and then just exits the `while(1)` loop. When I used the debugger, it stopped at `free()` one time at `cur->prev` and another time in the `else` statement within that `if` where `cur->prev`. It's just crashing randomly after doing what it was supposed to do after some time.

I'm just asking if you have any suggestions about what might be the cause.

It is meant to run constantly until someone presses <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Comment: In `players_u()`, `malloc (sizeof(node*))` should be `malloc (sizeof(node))`  You are not allocating your nodes correctly, so you will end up trashing memory if `sizeof(node)` is greater than `sizeof(node*)` and you access any members that are offset more than `sizeof(node*)` bytes in a `node`

Comment: thxxx didn't saw that

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: please post something one can compile in order to help you.

Comment: `casting` the result of `malloc` can be a lifesaver for you and your group, especially in complex or not so complex data structures where you allocate many types of things, sometimes in the same function. This "do not cast" thing is a myth from the 90's created by a [C_FAQ](https://c-faq.com/) and even there is a note about what I am saying. `C` is not `C++` where the code guidelines are kept updated and reviewed by a group of experts: this FAQ is from the 90's and before.

Comment: `f(root != NULL){` - Don't put everything in your function inside a big if. Check if `root == NULL` and exit the function immediately, then you can proceed with the rest one less indentation level deep safely knowing that `root` is not `NULL`.